# colored categories in r wordclouds

Tags: r, colors, word-cloud

Using the wordcloud package in R I would like to color different words according to a categorical variable in the dataset. Say my data is as follows:

```
  name weight group
1  Aba     10    x
2  Bcd     20    y
3  Cde     30    z
4  Def      5    x
```

And here as a `dput`:

```
dat <- structure(list(name = c("Aba", "Bcd", "Cde", "Def"), weight = c(10, 
    20, 30, 5), group= c("x", "y", "z", "x")), .Names = c("name", 
    "weight", "group"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is there a way in wordcloud() to color the names by their group (x, y, z) or should I use different software/packages?

Comment: You have the right package.  Could you please give us a sample of your data so we can provide an answer that helps future searchers too.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, does this data help to clarify? So Tom and Steph would be the same color because they are both in group(x), but since i set freq(mydata$weight) tom will appear larger than steph in the cloud.

Comment: I edited to make your data easier to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will automatically choose from a color list based on frequency or by word order if `ordered.colors` is specified.

```
name = c("Aba","Bcd","Cde","Def")
weight = c(10,20,30,5)
colorlist = c("red","blue","green","red")

wordcloud(name, weight, colors=colorlist, ordered.colors=TRUE)
```

[image: four-elements]

The example above works for independent variables. In a data frame, your color specification will be stored as a factor, and it will have to be converted to text by wrapping it in `as.character` like this:

```
wordcloud(df$name, df$weight, colors=as.character(df$color), ordered.colors=TRUE)
```

If you just have factors and not a list of colors, you can generate a parallel `colorlist` with a couple of lines.

```
#general solution for any number of categories
basecolors = rainbow(length(unique(group)))
# solution for known categories
basecolors = c("red","green","blue")

group = c("x","y","z","x")
# find position of group in list of groups, and select that matching color...
colorlist = basecolors[ match(group,unique(group)) ]
```

Comment: Do you want other groups like `x,y,z`, or do you already have color definitions in your data table? It has been evolving as your question is edited...

Comment: thanks for the help beroe, i gave this a shot but i still get invalid color specifications. I have around 1000 records in a table that I'm trying to use this on, so I'm not sure if your solution applies to my situation. But it would be best to provide a general solution so others can find this helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: The invalid specification is because in the data frame your color names are interpreted as factors. Wrap them in `as.character` like this: `wordcloud(df$name, df$weight, colors=as.character(df$color), ordered.colors=TRUE)`

Comment: The `as.character()` precision was exactly what I needed !