# Print a list to png image form

Tags: r

Lets say I have a list name Label1 such as below

```
[1] "adelaide"  "allah"     "ampamp"    "anak"      "anwar"     "audit"     "australia" "bajet"    
[9] "baru"      "bersama"   "blog"      "dato"      "doakan"    "dsai"      "eid"       "festival"
```

and I would like to just print it all out to an image (png). Any idea? Also include a title on the top if possible. I tried using

```
png(file.choose(), w=700, h=1000)
  par(mar=c(5,10,2,2))
  print(Label1)
dev.close()
```

However it just works for plot I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say `textplot` or even a [word cloud](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/index.html) is probably better, but here is a simple way that gives you some control...

```
Label1 = c("adelaide","allah","ampamp","anak","anwar","audit","australia","bajet","baru","bersama","blog","dato","doakan","dsai","eid","festival" )

# set up the empty frame
plot(c(0,100),c(0,100),xaxt='n',yaxt='n',type='n',xlab="",ylab="",
 main = "Image Title")

# set up the positions:
x = rep(seq(20,80,20),4)
y = c(20,20,20,20,40,40,40,40,60,60,60,60,80,80,80,80)

# plot the words using text()
text(x,y,Label1,col=rainbow(12))
```

Output:

[image]

An example of the word cloud option:

```
library(wordcloud)
require(RColorBrewer)
wordcloud(Label1, colors=(rep(brewer.pal(8,"Spectral"),2)), ordered.colors=TRUE)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped. Check out [wordclouds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902485/colored-categories-in-r-wordclouds) too for some fun. (I put a link to a different library in the original answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Try `textplot` in the gplots package.