# R Wordcloud Format

Tags: r, word-cloud, wordcloud2

I have tried to follow this example: [colorlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902485/colored-categories-in-r-wordclouds) to receive a wordcloud which uses the same colors for one label (regardless of frequency of words).

I tried to make use of my previous code so this is what I tried:

```
# Install
install.packages("tm")  # for text mining
install.packages("SnowballC") # for text stemming
install.packages("wordcloud") # word-cloud generator 
install.packages("RColorBrewer") # color palettes
# Load
library("tm")
library("SnowballC")
library("wordcloud")
library("RColorBrewer")
# Import Freq List
cname<-read.csv("/Users/mypath/wordcloud.csv",head=TRUE,encoding = "UTF-8") 
# Create Wordcloud 
set.seed(1234)
wordcloud(words = cname$word, freq = cname$count, min.freq = 1, max.words=200, min_font_size=12, colors = as.character(cname$color), ordered.colors=TRUE)
```

[CSV here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19F0GuNY2wQEF8t7Xpan-58SNXHDgZidh/view?usp=sharing)

So I am able to create a wordcloud, that looks like this: [image]

However what I would like to have is
a) a prettier color-palette (which doesnt hurt the eye as much) and
b) if possible for the words with the same color to be in one area each
c) a prettier font.

Is that doable somehow?

---

Update:

I made use of the code as per suggestion, but will receive a wrong mapping

[image]

```
# Install
install.packages("wordcloud2") # word-cloud generator 
install.packages("RColorBrewer") # color palettes
# Load
library(wordcloud2)
library(RColorBrewer)
cl <- brewer.pal(length(unique(cname$label)), "Spectral")
# Run
cname<-read.csv("/Users/wordcloud.csv", head=TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8") 
wordcloud2::wordcloud2(cname, rotateRatio = 0,
                       color = cl[as.numeric(as.factor(cname$label))],                        
                       fontFamily = "baskerville",
                       shape = "diamond")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wordcloud2 package. You can customize the rotation, shape, etc.

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(RColorBrewer)
cl <- brewer.pal(5, "Spectral")

wordcloud2::wordcloud2(words, rotateRatio = 0, 
                       color = cl[as.numeric(as.factor(words$label))],
                       fontFamily = "avenir",
                       shape = "diamond")
```

[image]

Edit:

You can also have

```
cl <- brewer.pal(length(unique(words$label)), "Spectral")
```

Here, the number of colours will match with the number of unique labels.

Comment: Thank you very much! the package works nice! just one question: I am using the exact same code sample but for my color code it won't match with the label for some reason, meaning the label will basically be ignored. Do I need to add some lines here?

Comment: Check the edit and let me know if this is what your query is about.

Comment: Thank you! Tried, but received the error: could not find function "len"

Comment: I'm sorry. It's length. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it as updated example above but will still receive a wrong color mapping. :/